# WPF .net5 Windows Server error: The framework Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App not found

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF application in .net5. I don't have any problem when publish app and run it in my local. But when I copy the publish folder to VM, this error displayed when click on app icon for run:

```
to run this application you must install .net.
the framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' version 5.0.0 was not found.
would you like to download it now?
```

This is my .runtimeconfig file:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
        "version": "5.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my dotnet --info:

```
C:\Users\apsydev>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100
 Commit:    5044b93829

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.2
  Commit:  cb5f173b96

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0-rc2-19460-02 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

As you can see, the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App ver 5.0.0 is installed in my .net solution. How could I solve this? Thank you

Comment: Ever figure it out? I am getting the same when I install app to clean machines, even though I am including a few .NET Core prerequisites....

Comment: Yes my problem was on my build command. I built release app on x86 but VM was x64!